# Can't Ping External Network on Ubuntu

Tags: networking, dns

I installed BIND on Ubuntu and nslookup is successful, pinging my hostname is successful, but pinging an external site (i.e. www.google.com) does not work.

I receive the error message: **ping: unknown host www.website.com**

Any ideas why I can't ping an external network? Here are my settings:

**ifconfig** (snippet)

```
eth0 
     inet addr: 192.0.2.100    Bcast:192.0.2.4    Mask: 255.255.255.0

lo  
    inet addr: 127.0.0.1    Mask:255.0.0.0
```

**/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1    testing    testing.local    localhost
127.0.1.1    testing
```

**/etc/hostname**

```
testing.local
```

**/etc/network/interfaces**

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static

address   192.0.2.100
netmask   255.255.255.0
network   192.0.2.0
broadcast 192.0.2.4
gateway   192.0.2.1
```

**/etc/resolv.conf**

```
nameserver   192.0.2.100 
search       testing.local 
domain       testing.local
```

**/etc/bind/named.conf.options**

```
forwarders {
192.0.2.1;
8.8.8.8;
8.8.4.4;
};
```

**etc/bind/named.conf.local**

```
#FORWARD LOOKUP ZONE

zone "testing.local"
{
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/zones/testing.local.db";
};

#REVERSE LOOKUP ZONE

zone "0.0.192.in-addr.arpa"
{
   type master;
   file "rev.0.0.192.in-addr.arpa";
};
```

**/etc/bind/zones/testing.local.db** #FORWARD LOOKUP

```
$ORIGIN testing.local.

$TTL 3D

@    SOA    testing.local.    admin.testing.local. (12 4h 1h 1w 1h)

@                 IN     NS     testing.local.

testing.local.    IN    A  192.0.2.100

www               IN    A  192.0.2.100
```

**/etc/bind/zones/rev.0.0.10.in-addr.arpa**  #REVERSE LOOKUP

```
$ORIGIN    testing.local.

$TTL 3D

@    SOA    testing.local.    admin.testing.local. (12 4h 1h 1w 1h)

@          IN     NS     testing.local.

1          IN     PTR    testing.local.
```

I'm not sure if it matters but I have not yet installed/configured DHCP yet. I also uninstalled my network-manager since it was interfering with my settings. I know I put a lot of information, basically everything I edited but I am a newbie and I've spent all day trying to figure it out. I thank you all in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'unknown host' means that you are not able to determine the IP address associated with this particular domain name. The two possibilities are:

1. You cannot find the DNS server
2. DNS server doesn't know of www.website.com

Try doing `dig www.website.com`, that will give you an idea of what it is that you are trying to ping. Most likely you are looking at the lack of the DNS server in your settings.

Comment: I tried dig and I get: <<>> DiG 9.8.1-P1 <<>> www.google.com ;; global options: +cmd ;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached. I also checked the syslog and I notice that I have a "[5306] error (network unreachable) resolving" - solution I've found is to change the /etc/sysconfig/named file with OPTIONS="-4". How would I do that on Ubuntu 12.04? (there is no sysconfig/named file)